# .NET Maui change linewidth of checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, .net-maui

I have following XAML code:

```
<HorizontalStackLayout>
     <CheckBox x:Name="isItemChecked" IsChecked="False" CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" Color="Blue" ></CheckBox>
     <Label Text="Include Item" FontAttributes="Bold" Padding="5"></Label>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

I'm currently trying to increase the line width of the unchecked checkbox. It seems pretty trivial but it's not that easy to google. (At least I did not find an entry in the official documentation.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've read your question. You may consider using the checkbox visual state to realize it.

Comment: @HongxinSui - the word "change" in question is ambiguous. Your suggestion would work, if person meant "dynamically change from current value to different value". Here, it is a different meaning: Person cannot find a property on `CheckBox`, that sets linewidth. Therefore, visual state cannot fix this. But you had good suggestion that may help someone else later, so thank you.

Comment: There might not be such an option in Maui. You could make your own custom control, that "acts like a checkbox". Its a bit of work, and sorry I'm not able currently to show how to do this. Maybe a `StackLayout` containing a `Button` that has two different images, for "on" and "off".

Comment: Use https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use ScaleX and  ScaleY property for checkbox.
There is an example:

```
<CheckBox  ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
```